# Update primary key in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I currently developing a web based application for a client. the requirement given that I should make a function that allows them to update clientID(PK). I'm planning on using gridview to make it easier. However, I dont really know how to make the primary key field can be updated.

in my client table i have: clientID(PK), clientName, clientAddress etc.

If anyone can tell me how to do it i would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primary key is something you don't want to update, as it will break foreign key references. If the client needs an ID that needs to be changed it will just have to be another field in your table and not the primary key.

Comment: my client is a school board. In my country, when u r below 12 years old, they stored ur birth certificate number as ID in school, but after that u will get a Identification Card and the number on the card will be used to be stored as studentID. that is why my client need to update the primary key.

Comment: That doesn't mean it should be the primary key.  The primary key can/should be an auto-incrementing integer.  You may be thinking of a look-up field that is indexed for speed.

Comment: I still think that StudentID should be a column in your student table that is not primary key. Just add an Id column which is the primary key and link that to class rooms and school results and what not. That way the StudentID can be updated without loosing those references. The StudentID can also be printed on report while the internal primary key will never be visible to the users (which is not uncommon for primary keys)

Comment: The "it will break foreign key references" doesn't make sense, as you can use cascading relationship constraints. I've just posted a solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_rowupdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
    e.NewValues("id2")=e.NewValues("id")
End Sub

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataSourceID="ds_myTable" DataKeyNames="id" Runat="Server">
<columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"/> 
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Id" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" /> 
    <asp:BoundField DataField="someField" HeaderText="someField" />     
</columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource id="ds_myTable"
    ConnectionString="<%$ connectionStrings: ... %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings: ... %>"  
    SelectCommand="SELECT * from myTable Order By id;"
    UpdateCommand= "UPDATE myTable SET id=@id2,someField=@someField WHERE id=@id"
    runat="Server">
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="someField" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
</UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```